# Child Composites not appearing in layout

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to build a GUI where multiple composites are layed out vertically. I put my approach in a minimal example:

```
public class LayoutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(400, 300);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Composite listPanel = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER
                | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        listPanel.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
        listPanel.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(
                SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

            Composite listElement = new Composite(listPanel, SWT.BORDER);
            listElement.setLayout(new RowLayout());

            Label label = new Label(listElement, SWT.BORDER);
            label.setText(String.valueOf(i) + "     foo");
            label.setSize(label.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

            listElement.setSize(label.computeSize(shell.getSize().x,
                    label.getSize().y));
        }

        shell.layout(true, true);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

You can see that some composites are created in a loop. The problem is that only the first appears in the UI. I would expect them to be layed out below each other since it's parent has a vertical `RowLayout`.

I also tried other approaches. One was a one column `GridLayout` the other was a `FormLayout` where I set the top attachment of each child to the previous. Both showed exactly the same result.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    ScrolledComposite listPanel = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    listPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite child = new Composite(listPanel, SWT.NONE);
    child.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button(child, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("lalala");

        Label label = new Label(child, SWT.BORDER);
        label.setText(i + "     foo");
    }

    Point size = child.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);

    listPanel.setContent(child);
    listPanel.setMinSize(size.x, size.y);
    listPanel.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    listPanel.setExpandVertical(true);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

The important part that was missing is this:

```
listPanel.setContent(child);
listPanel.setMinSize(size.x, size.y);
listPanel.setExpandHorizontal(true);
listPanel.setExpandVertical(true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just for understanding: The `ScrolledComposite` can only have one child so I have wrap my multiple children in an extra `Composite`?